# ap-hotspot cannot connect to android devices

Tags: wireless, android, hot-spot

I created a hotspot using `ap-hotspot` in my ubuntu 12.10.
The created hotspot shows in my android phone but it get stucks in obtaining IP address.. How can I add an IP address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just fix the same problem, try this:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Change the line that says:

```
dns=dnsmasq
```

To:

```
#dns=dnsmasq
```

Restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: Thanx dude......it helped me !!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe caused by a certain firewall application or service you can disable and find out the culprit.

```
eg ufw service
```